Проблема с запуском c++ в Visual Studio Code в терминале
Я только начала изучать C++, в качестве среды разработки я выбрала Visual Studio Code для macOs и столкнулась со следующей проблемой: при запуске/при запуске с отладкой C++ файла, программа начинает выполняться в Debug Console, а не в терминале. Если при запуске выбрать именно «Запустить код из файла», всё работает нормально - программа запускается в терминале. Но в остальных двух случаях - нет. К меня стоит Code runner и в настройках у меня стоит code-runner:Run In Terminal:true, но это не решило моей проблемы. Получается, что в режиме отладки код не запускается из терминала, как в таком случае вводить данные в режиме отладки(через консоль отладки не получается)?
В качестве компилятора я использую clang++
Подскажите пожалуйста, как мне решить данную проблему

добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! как задать хороший вопрос. стоит начать с формулировки заголовка.
